# How do i add onClick listener that would return the value of the clicked list from this code? (this is my first time coding andorid)

Tags: android

I've found this code from here
[github](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/samples/database-v1/src/main/java/com/example/MyDatabase.java)

I've already created a Class with a method that would take the returned value from the list and retrieve appropriate value from database based on the value.

All i need right now is an onClick handler for this code that would return me a value of the clicked item on the list.

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private Cursor employees;
private MyDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    db = new MyDatabase(this);
    employees = db.getDisease(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            employees,
            new String[] {"FirstName"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    employees.close();
    db.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at the [`ListActivity#onListItemClick()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)).

Comment: It took me a while to read it but finally found out how to use onListItemClick method() thanks a lot.